# Elasticsearch: combine cutoff_frequency with the and operator?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have come across some elasticsearch queries combining cutoff_frequency with the "and" operator, but this does not make sense to me.

This is part of the bool query:

```
  {
    "match": {
      "content": {
        "query": "I has candy and cake",
        "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
```

And according to this documentation the cutoff_frequency will (depending on the documents, but most likely) transform this into the following;

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": { 
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          { "term": { "text": "candy" }},
          { "term": { "text": "cake"  }}
        ]
      }
    },
    "should": { 
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          { "term": { "text": "I" }},
          { "term": { "text": "has" }},
          { "term": { "text": "and" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what happens since there is an "and" operator added to the query? Does this mean that the "cutoff_frequency" has no effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has an effect.
From documentation [Elastic Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

> The match query supports a **cutoff_frequency** that allows specifying an absolute or relative document frequency where high-frequency terms are moved into an optional subquery and are **only scored if** one of the low frequency (below the cutoff) terms in the case of an or operator or **all of the low-frequency terms in the case of an and operator match**.

**UPDATE**: I have been mistaken in query

Looks like that:

```
{
 "bool": {
    "must": { 
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "term": { "text": "candy" }},
          { "term": { "text": "cake"  }}
       ]
     }
    },
 "should": { 
    "bool": {
       "should": [
         { "term": { "text": "I" }},
         { "term": { "text": "has" }},
         { "term": { "text": "and" }}
       ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

And answering your question "Yes only if match both term"

Comment: So in my example above, the high frequency terms (I, has, and) will only contribute to the scoring if all of my low frequency terms (candy, cake) are in a document?